# Couldn't deserialize json object from DB with with jackson.databind

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I tried to deserialize a json from db and he couldn't deserialize him due to "'" value.

Actually the json in DB saved with "value":"'" (single quote mark).

The exception that I receive is:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: {"criterionDtos":[{"criterionId":null,"columnId":"S5000","operatorId":310,"values":[{"value":""","displayValue":null,"id":null}],"isWarningBubble":false}]}; line: 1, column: 197]

The expected behavior is received the the complete json that saved.

Comment: What is the target type of the 'value' field?
Have you tried to use your custom deserializer: 
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDeserializer.class)

Comment: I just want to receive the json from db